# Сохранить данные в одну клетку массива в цикле

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы, arraylist

Имеется цикл процессов. Например [такой](http://jsfiddle.net/montel388/vPatQ/139/). Система может иметь несколько студий для каждого процесса. Что я хочу сделать это сохранять полученные студии для каждого процесса и сохранять их в одну клетку массива разделенную запятыми. Чтобы позже я мог взять полученные студии для каждого процесса и сохранить их в базу данных.

Моя функция с помощью которой я пытаюсь сохранить данные:

```
var LISTOBJ = {
  saveList: function() {
    $(".output").html("");
    var listCSV = [];
    $(".studio").each(function() {

      $(this).find("input").each(function() {
        listCSV.push($(this).text());
      });
      var values = '' + listCSV.join(',') + '';
      $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='studio[]' value='" + values + "' />");
      $("#output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
      console.debug(listCSV);
    });
  }
}
```

Как я могу исправить данную функцию, чтобы сохранять студии с одного процесса вместе?
В итоге я хочу получать что то такое:

```
Array ( [0] => ,APEX, BASECAMP [1] => , CANVAS, ORBIT)
```

Comment: Здорово! Что Вы хотите от нас?

Comment: по коду: сколько у Вас элементов ".output" и сколько "#output"? или `var listCSV = [];` надо внести внутрь `$(".studio").each(function() {` или `var values = '' + listCSV.join(',') + ''; ...` - вынести.

Comment: @Igor код изменил. Можете посмотреть [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/montel388/vPatQ/144/) проблема что сохраняет только с одного процесса

Comment: у Вас в html только первый `select` имеет класс `studio`, поставьте этот класс второму `select`у тоже

Comment: @Igor точно, уже исправил.

Comment: @igor однако теперь другая проблема теперь все сохраняется в одну клетку массива: `Array ( [0] => APEX, BASECAMP, TOONIGAMI )` хотя должно быть так: `Array ( [0] => APEX, BASECAMP [1] => TOONIGAMI ) ` Как я могу поделить так чтобы функция сохраняла студии для каждого процесса отдельно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. У Вас в html только первый `select` имеет класс `studio`, поставьте этот класс второму `select`у тоже.
2. В Вашем коде все `select`ы с классом `studio` попадают в один список.

   ```
   var LISTOBJ = {
      saveList: function() {
        $(".output").html("");
        $("table").has(".studio").each(function() {
          var listCSV = [];
          $(this).find(".studio").each(function() {
            var text = $(this).val();
            if (text) {
              listCSV.push(text);
            }
            var values = '' + listCSV.join(',') + '';
            $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='studio[]' value='" + values + "' />");
            $(".output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");
          });
        });
      }
    }
   ```

Comment: Интегрировал Ваш код в мой, а также вынес ` var values = '' + listCSV.join(',') + '';
         $(".output").append("<input type='text' name='studio[]' value='" + values + "' />");
         $(".output").append("<p>" + values + "</p>");` за вторую each функцию. Все заработало как надо. Посмотреть можно [тут](http://jsfiddle.net/montel388/vPatQ/156/) Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy А, точно, это мой прокол, прошу прощения. Успехов в программировании.